# Apply string formatting to list-join

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do the following:

```
node = ''.join(c_info['in']+c_info['out'])
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Resistor found
```

Is there a dunder method that I can add/modify so that a string join will work with instances of that class? Or do I need to manually do the string formatting? Otherwise, what I'm doing is:

```
node = ''.join([str(item) for item in (c_info['in'] + c_info['out'])])
```

Comment: `1+1=2` is logical but why would you want `1+1=11`. And it's less used so not implemented by python developer.

Comment: @Ch3steR `join` works on a string field, not numeric.

Comment: @Ch3steR if i understand it correctly this is not the point here. the question is more: can i turn an arbitrary class into something that makes a list of this class' objects string-joinable

Comment: You need to manually do string formatting, even if you implement `__str__` and `__repr__` you'll have to be explicit about wanting a string.

Comment: @samuelbrody192 Yes, that what I was saying `join` only works string and implemented only for strings explicitly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe got it, thanks. That was the answer I was looking for (if you want to put it in an answer I can accept that).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `+` operator in your `Resistor` to explicitly return the kind of type you want. (Which, incidentally, also means you do *not* need `join` anymore.)

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, initial_value = 0):
        self.bar = initial_value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return str(self.bar)+str(other.bar)

foo1 = Foo(10)
foo2 = Foo(20)

print (foo1+foo2)
```

Result (a regular string):

```
1020
```

Comment: what if there are 1000 resistors to join?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: ultimately you have to convert them *somewhere* to a string, if you are determined to use `join` in another part of your code. But your question does not contain enough detail to suggest any more.